# Mismatch between Jquery and Sharepoint

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am working on an existing page build with Jquery and sharepoint
The page already contain a jquery script that makes news scroll down .
I cant access the old code to add some , so i did add a content web part with sharepoint where i can add all my code and then submit

i added this code:

```
<script src="/_catalogs/masterpage/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(the same as the default page)

```
$('img#test').click(function(){

alert('testttttt');
});
```

Its a simple code just to see if all is working
but what i see is when i refer to jquery.js in mmy code, the old scrolling will stop working and my code will work
and if i delete the link , my code wont work and the old code will work
any advices?

another thing , instead of doing this , i tryed to add

```
 < img onClick='test1' id='id1'... />
```

to the html , but sharepoint is keeping deleting the code for me

```
 < img id='id1' .... />
```

any advices?
thank u

Comment: What happens if you remove your link to jQuery, then put your JS inside a document.ready() block?

Comment: it wont work when i remove the Jquery link

Comment: all i need now is to call a javascript function , already built in system called HideToMenu , but i cant do it from any part , if i do it from html , sharepoint will erase the call , and if i do it from jquery , the scrolling  will stop

Comment: if the scrolling stops, then most likely the javascript aborted in the initialization phase. you must use client-side debugging tools to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is this:

Open the page using FireBug addon in FireFox or use the Developer Tools in IE to inspect the page.

Goto the script tab and check which scripts are being included.  If the page already referenced JQuery then you should not need to include it again within your Content Editor WebPart.

If you establish that JQuery is being included already in the page then your javascript above should work fine.

If it's included in the page already and your code doesn't work, then it may be that your sample JS code is wrong.

But a good start would be to check the rendered page within the dev tools mention above to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Thank u man for ur help , but what i wanted to say that i cant append to the old script because these are standard templates , so i cant add code. this is why i added a Content webPart